# c# compiler error when passing `this` to a delegate that accepts generic parameter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following abstract class that I would like to leverage to create event channels for a unity project. I'm having trouble with understanding how generics work in C# (this language is new to me) and receiving a compiler error concerning passing `this` as an argument when invoking the listeners.

```
namespace EventManagers
{
    public abstract class EventSubject<T> : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public delegate void Listener<T>(T eventSubject);

        private readonly 
            List<Listener<T>> _listeners = new List<Listener<T>>();

        public void Attach(Listener<T> listener)
        {
            _listeners.Add(listener);
        }

        public void Detach(Listener<T> listener)
        {
            _listeners.Remove(listener);
        }

        public void NotifyObservers()
        {
            foreach (Listener<T> listener in _listeners)
            {
                listener(this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error referring to the line that reads `listener(this);`:

```
 error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'EventManagers.EventSubject<T>' to 'T'
```

An inheriting class looks like:

```
public class Selection : EventSubject<Selection> {
    private GameObject selected;
    private static Selection _instance;

    public static Selection instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (!_instance)
            {
                _instance = FindObjectOfType(typeof (Selection)) as Selection;
                if (!_instance) {
                    throw new Exception("You need a Selection in the scene");
                }
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    
    public GameObject GetSelection() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelection(GameObject selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
        NotifyObservers();
    }
}
```

My questions are:

1. If my delegate knows to expect a generic type why is this problematic?
2. How can I best achieve this event pattern?

Comment: Do you want a "curiously recursive" generic constraint? eg `EventSubject<T> : MonoBehaviour where T:EventSubject<T>`? Though I think you'll still need a runtime cast `(T)this`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cs
public abstract class EventSubject<T> : MonoBehaviour { ... }
public class Selection : EventSubject<Selection> { ... }
```

From the POV of your `EventSubject` class, `typeof(T)` could be anything at all. It could even be `EventSubject<int>` since you haven't provided any `where` constraints. The compiler has no way of knowing that you expect `typeof(T) == this.GetType()`.

The pattern you are looking for was nicknamed [Curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) in C++. In C#, the equivalent generic constraint is;

```cs
public abstract class EventSubject<T> : MonoBehaviour 
    where T : EventSubject<T>
{
    ...
    public void NotifyObservers()
    {
        foreach (Listener listener in _listeners)
        {
            listener((T)this);
        }
    }
}

public class Selection : EventSubject<Selection> { ... }
```

This is close to what you want, as it at least limits `T` to classes that extend `EventSubject<>`. But the compiler still can't prove that `typeof(T) == this.GetType()`, so you need an explicit cast.

This constraint also allows `class Broken : EventSubject<Selection>`, and there isn't any C# language feature that can prevent it. The best you can do is a runtime exception if a developer breaks your `typeof(T) == this.GetType()` rule.

Comment: Ah thank you for the explanation. This helps my understand.

Answer (score 0):

1. Listener is expecting `Selection` instance, you're passing `this` which is a `Listener<Selection>` instance.
2. Event pattern is built-in in c# language - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-subscribe-to-and-unsubscribe-from-events
   You basically reimplemented it without any advantages.

Comment: _"Event pattern...You basically reimplemented it without any advantages"_ - there's nothing wrong with re-inventing things.   Particularly when the one in .NET leads to memory leaks.

Comment: @MickyD: his implementation leads to the same memory leaks. It's important to understand how events work underneath

Comment: @Adassko for #1 Would you care to explain further? Could you example what is incorrect and maybe provide an example of what the correct code might look like?

#2 I appreciate the suggestion however, as `@MickyD` pointed out I'm looking to implement my own as I'm hoping this will give me a larger understanding of the language.

Comment: As a c# novice I would also love to hear about the memory leak risks here and optimizations to mitigate them.

Comment: If you never remove an element from `_listeners`, and those delegates represent instance methods, then those instances can't be garbage collected. The same is true with unsubscribing from events as they are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

For others who may be viewing I was able to achieve a working result. My EventSubject class now appears as follows:

```
public abstract class EventSubject<TEventSubject> : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public delegate void Listener(TEventSubject eventSubject);

        private readonly
            List<Listener> _listeners = new List<Listener>();

        public void Attach(Listener listener)
        {
            _listeners.Add(listener);
        }

        public void Detach(Listener listener)
        {
            _listeners.Remove(listener);
        }

        public void NotifyObservers(TEventSubject eventSubject)
        {
            foreach (Listener listener in _listeners)
            {
                listener(eventSubject);
            }
        }
    }
```

and my `Selection` class now looks like this:

```
public class Selection : EventSubject<Selection> {
    private GameObject selected;
    private static Selection _instance;

    public static Selection instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (!_instance)
            {
                _instance = FindObjectOfType(typeof (Selection)) as Selection;
                if (!_instance) {
                    throw new Exception("You need a Selection in the scene");
                }
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    
    public GameObject GetSelection() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelection(GameObject selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
        NotifyObservers(this);
    }
}
```

I honestly never solved the riddle of why the compiler did not like `listener(this)` but was able to work around that by making it an argument of `NotifyObservers`. I would love to hear optimizations or other things people would change.